# See which table a result is in

Tags: php, mysql

I took over managing an internal website for the company that I'm working for and I need to get data out of a mysql database.  The problem that I'm encountering is that the data is in 6 different tables, all with the same fields but the rows are all unique (the row starts in one table and then gets completely moved to a different table after it is processed by an employee).

Is there an easy way to query against all 6 at once?  It would also be useful to be able to retrieve the title of the table it came from.

I'm using PHP to run the query and display it.  Would it be better to create another table that defines where all the rows are, have a unique id and then another field for which table it's in?

Comment: "Would it be better to create another table that defines where all the rows are, have a unique id and then another field for which table it's in?" Yes, this is a classic design pattern.

Comment: Been there. Good luck, you'll need it.

Answer (score 0):

To complete this query, use `union all`:

```
select
    'Table1' as TableName,
    *
from
    Table1
union all
select
    'Table2',
     *
from
    Table2
union all
select
    'Table3',
    *
from
    Table3
```

...and so on

For better database design, you would want to either have one table with *all* the rows in it, and a designated Status table where you can link a StatusID column to that says what status that given row is in. A table for each stage in a process is a poor design and will only lead to *massive* headaches down the road.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't reorganize the tables so that you have just one with all rows and a marker for where in the process they are, I would go for a `UNION`-approach. Ie:

```
SELECT 'Data from Table 1', t1.field1, ...
  FROM Table1 t1
 UNION
SELECT 'Data from Table 2', t2.field1, ...
  FROM Table2 t2
 UNION
 (Table3, 4, 5 and 6 in the same manner)
....
```

That way you can see where the data is originating from and you get all 6 at once. Just remember that you have to have the exact same field list in all parts of the `UNION`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a code generator that generates SQL statements to query the 6 tables. The generator would create a UNION of 6 selects and add a "table" column to each select with a constant value equal to the name of the table queried. That would make writing the statements easy, though I wouldn't say that writing the generator would be.